# Подключение классов в Laravel

Tags: laravel

Как подключить класс Form в Laravel версии 6.15.1?

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с формами в blade ларавел (ещё с 5-ки) заменили конструкции типа:

```
{{Form::open()}}
                <input type="checkbox" name="task" id="task_{{$task->id}}"
                {{$task->status ? 'checked' : ''}} onclick="this.form.submit()" />
                <input type="hidden" name="task_id" value="{{$task->id}}"
                <label for="task_{{$task->id}}">{{$task->content}}</label>
                <a href = "delete/{{$task->id}}">Х</a>
            {{Form::close()}}
```

на такие (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#forms), подключать ничего не надо:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile" class="red-circle">
    @csrf

    ...
</form>
```

Это удобно во многих отношениях, в том числе для стилизации форм, по моему Вы задавали такой вопрос. Попробуйте использовать такой подход, а будут вопросы обращайтесь!)